# jQuery Can not set timeout

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

So I have a data table which has two columns, one column contains an anchor the other an image.

This is what I need to do. Click the first link, open it in a new tab. wait some time, close the tab continue on to the next. This is what I have so far.

I will not I an very new to this javascript and jQuery stuff.

So with this I can get the list of anchors and click anyone I want, problem is that it opens in a new window and using `.attr('target', '_blank')` has not worked for me.

```
$("#tables").find('a').get(0).click()
```

After the anchor is clicked the anchor will disappear on page load, so I only ever really need to know where the first anchor is. So this is what I need.

Click anchor 0, wait 30s close opened tab, refresh, repeat until no anchors are found.

This is what I am working with so far.

```
function clickAds() {
if ($("#tables").find('a').length > 0) {    
    $("#tables").find('a').get(0).click();  
    setTimeout(clickAds() 35000);

    location.reload()
   };

  clickAds()
```

I have edited my problem and now have code that clicks the same link over and over again until chrome chrashes. I can not get the timeout to work! Does anyone have any idea as to why?

Comment: `What I can not get working is the new tab` what is not working with it? Also once your page is reloaded your javascript will restart.

Comment: I updated the code, and I can not get the setTimeOut to work

Comment: `setTimeout(clickAds, 35000);` and remove  `location.reload()` from true condition :) remove `.get(0)` (change to first())... take a look to debugger console...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change Your code from:

```
function clickAds() {
if ($("#tables").find('a').length > 0) {    
    $("#tables").find('a').get(0).click();  
    setTimeout(clickAds() 35000);

    location.reload()
   };
```

to this:

```
function clickAds() 
{
    if ($("#tables").find('a').length > 0) 
    {    
        $("#tables").find('a').get(0).click();  
        setTimeout(clickAds, 35000);
       // location.reload()
    }
}
```

Your if block did not seem right as I did not see the closing brace.  Then in your timeout dont include the braced() but rater just the callback function's name.

Another way would be to to this:

```
function clickAds() 
{
    if ($("#tables").find('a').length > 0) 
    {    
        $("#tables").find('a').get(0).click();  
        setTimeout(function()
        {
           clickAds();
         }, 35000);
       // location.reload()
    }
}
```

Where you give the timeout its own callback function that calls the clickAds function

Comment: I will be trying this tonight. What is the difference between the two solutions you provided? Both provide a callback and set the timeout. Is the second just explicit. If I understand properly the JS interpreter would run them the same.

Comment: The second option merely provides the time out with its own handler which then calls your method. Sometimes you may want to call different methods depending on a condition.  In your case the first option is fine.

Comment: now do you know how to close other tabs with jQuery? I haven't looked into their tab api yet.